# Integrating PURGE into Mac OS X Application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I want to run command line     "purge" programmatically. I know that I can do a shell exec and call      "purge" but my problem is that purge is not included in Mac OS 10.6 and below and will be installed if you install Developer Tools.
Wondering how I can ship      purge via my application and/or install that if is not there.

More info:

```
 Platform : MAC OS X 
 IDE:  XCode 4.6
 Lang: Obj-C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't.**

The purpose of `purge` is described in the manual thus:

> Purge can be used to approximate initial boot conditions with a cold disk
>   buffer cache for performance analysis.

The only effect that it has on an end-user's system is to make the system perform worse while the cache is repopulated. It should **NOT** be used as part of "memory cleaner" tools, as the only effects it has are negative. (Indeed, these tools should not be used.) If the system actually needs memory, disk caches will be purged as necessary.

Comment: I'm sure that it's cleaning up the in-active memory!

Comment: That memory is just fine the way it is. It does not need to be "cleaned up".

Comment: Can't you just answer my question instead of arguing on this?

Comment: No. What you are trying to do is pointless and harms uninformed users.